# Can reactive components affect resistive impedance of circuit (Smith chart question)

Tags: impedance-matching

I'm failing to understand something. Impedance matching by complex conjugate can be defined as this: *"For two impedances to be complex conjugates, their resistances must be equal, and their reactances must be equal in magnitude but of opposite signs. "* But, I have seen many Smith chart examples, where it looks like people add only reactive elements (while starting out with different resistive impedances in the source and load), and somehow achieve the complex conjugate. I do not understand why. It seems contradictory to the definition: *" their resistances must be equal, and their reactances must be equal in magnitude but of opposite signs".* In the video screenshot below for example, the resistive impedances in the source and load are different, but somehow a complex conjugate is achieved anyway.

I might be misunderstanding something fundamental. I usually tend to be able to understand things. I asked two other questions on a related topic, but, they all derive from this fundamental issue that I cannot understand, so it is better that I ask about it directly.

An easy example of how reactive elements can change resistive impedance, could be good. The simplest possible, with as few parts as possible.

[image]

Edit: I've now had the effect demonstrated to myself by simulating Andy's example in Falstad. And that is what I was looking for. The effect is similar to a boost converter or other voltage increasers. It wastes a lot of current to achieve the voltage boost, just like a boost converter.

Comment: Yes reactive components can change the resistive component.  Designing VHF and UHF Class C  transmitters, we regularly transformed the transistor output impedance ( 1 or 2 ohms ) using shunt capacitors and series inductors to 50 ohms impedance.

Comment: I mean to ask more: how? I know they can, I can easily follow the lines in the Smith chart. As for how, I see some contradictions. It seems to have to do with shunts, parallel reactive elements. But, during impedance matching, the reactance should be neutralized and the elements at resonance. Then, any shunt should act like a short circuit. This not just decreases the resistance of the load, it removes it completely. To not remove it, there has to be some reactance in shunt. Then, maybe the resonance is when source+load is combined, but not locally in the load. Overall, I am missing something.

Comment: We were making wideband transmitters, resonance was undesirable.

Comment: It's simply arithmetic on the complex plane. You have two operations available to you: parallel (Zeff = Z1 Z2 / (Z1 + Z2)) and series (Zeff = Z1 + Z2). All else can be derived from this. If you aren't understanding impedances and matching, you really aren't understanding complex arithmetic. Admittedly it's one of the worst named sets, but therein seems to lie your confusion.

Comment: I'm able to understand complex arithmetic for other things. And, even if my understanding of it was limited in those cases, I have no problem with knowing how or why something works, and I have no problem testing it with simulations or practically to show that it works. Like calculating magnitude as hypothenuse of "real and imaginary" component. So I think I'd be able to understand the issue of this question too, good enough.

Comment: If resistance can be reduced by adding reactance, then I also think it is possible to understand that without any "complex arithmetics". It can just be proven, practically. Having to derive everything from math, is not really necessary, people often try to jump directly to math when explaining things, they would speed up learning curve 10x-100x to more, if they just explained it practically instead first.

Comment: @BipedalJoe I agree with your statement about not using math but, on this particular occasion it's not possible; it's fundamentally a math thing.

Answer (score 4):

> *I have seen many Smith chart examples, where it looks like people add
> only reactive elements (while starting out with different resistive
> impedances in the source and load), and somehow achieve the complex
> conjugate.*

When matching **different** resistive impedances, the use of complex conjugates is not as obvious as when matching **same-value** resistive impedances. The approach taken uses reactive components in a different way. Nevertheless, complex conjugate matching does take place.

> *An easy example of how reactive elements can change resistive
> impedance, could be good. The simplest possible, with as few parts as
> possible.*

It comes down to circuit examples like this (called L-pads): -

[image]

The above image (taken from [my basic website calculator](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20LP.html)) uses an inductor and parallel capacitor to match a 50 Ω source to a 300 Ω load at at a particular operating frequency.

The math is on the link above but, taking a different route, just consider this well-known fact; a parallel capacitor and resistor (\$C_{PAR}, R_{PAR}\$) can be converted to a series capacitor and resistor (\$C_{SER}, R_{SER}\$) with an identical complex impedance at a particular frequency.

And, we choose \$C_{PAR}\$ so that the resulting equivalent \$R_{SER}\$ matches the value of \$R_{SOURCE}\$. Thus we achieve a complex conjugate situation but via a slightly more deviating route.

> *I might be misunderstanding something fundamental.*

Parallel values (\$C_{PAR}, R_{PAR}\$) \$\rightarrow\$ series values (\$C_{SER}, R_{SER}\$) at a particular frequency: -

[image]

The image above (edited by me) was taken from [this calculator](https://wcalc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/parallel_rc.cgi?Cs=142.353&wc_unit_menu_0_0=pF&Rs=50&wc_unit_menu_1_0=Ohm&Qs=2.23607&Cp=118.6271&Rp=300&wc_unit_menu_2_0=Ohm&Qp=2.23607&freq=10&wc_unit_menu_3_0=MHz&stype=use_R&p2s=Parallel+to+Series). Basically I started with \$C_{PAR}\$ of 118.627 pF in parallel with 300 Ω resistive and, after pressing the button I got an equivalent series resistance of 50 Ω.

In short, at 10 MHz, a parallel capacitor of 118.627 pF and 300 Ω resistor is equivalent to a series circuit of 50 Ω and 142.353 pF. And, if you explore this a tad more, you will find that the equivalent series capacitance of 142.353 pF (-j111.8) is an equal magnitude reactance to the 1.779406 μH (+j111.8) inductor shown in the calculator below (from my basic website): -

[image].

Hence, complex conjugates are used although it's a little tricky to see on first view. The title question (that I initially forgot to answer) is this: -

> *Can reactive components affect resistive impedance of circuit*

Absolutely they can and hopefully, that should now be clear.

> *I asked two other questions on a related topic, but, they all derive
> from this fundamental issue that I cannot understand, so it is better
> that I ask about it directly.*

Yes, please revisit them and note that on the [one I answered](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/665344/20218) I have tried to make my answer clearer in lieu of this question.

---

**Why a simple L-pad provides 100% energy efficient impedance matching**

The example above makes a 300 Ω load to look like a 50Ω load. So, if 1 volt RMS is applied to the input, 20 mA RMS is drawn i.e. it appears to be a 50 Ω load. That's a power in of 20 mW.

Because it's a 100% efficient process, the power to the 300 Ω load is also 20 mW and, by simple math, we know that the load voltage is 2.44949 volts.

- Using ohm's law, the current is 8.165 mA.
- So, the input current is 20 mA and the output current is 8.165 mA.
- That's a current ratio of 2.44949:1

The voltage step-up ratio of 1:2.44949 might be usefully verified using a simulator: -

[image]

So, although the current in the load is reduced by 2.44949, the voltage increases by 2.44949 hence, the power remains the same i.e. a 100% energy efficient process. While I'm at it it's worth showing the input impedance in terms of reactance magnitude and phase angle: -

[image]

Comment: power of 5 mW on http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20LP.html, is 25% of 1 V through 50 Ohm (and 100% of 0.5 V through 50 Ohm), is maximum power that can be transferred theoretically around 25% then? and any non-matches will be less than 25%? any conceptualization around that 25% figure in literature or is it a dumb way to think about it?

Comment: A power of 5 mW in a 50 ohm resistor is 0.5 volts. For the rest of what you said I'm not understanding what you mean or how it connects to the website. The  number "25" does not appear on that webpage @BipedalJoe

Comment: well you don't have to.

Comment: If you want your comment addressing then I do need to.

Comment: thanks to your example, I could demonstrate to myself that reactive components did change the "real" component of the impedance. from 300 Ohm, to 50 Ohm. and, the reactive component were at resonance, so they add 0 Ohm. so, I assume it is correct to say that reactive components can change the "real" part of impedance?

Comment: Absolutely the reactive components can convert one resistance value into another in the particular circuit in my answer.

Comment: and, the complex conjugate in impedance matching, if the source impedance also had 1.779406 µH inductance, we could find the complex conjugate for it (where reactance cancels out, and we are left with only resistance, and have to adapt to source resistance because it cannot be changed) for 300 Ohm resistor load using a 118.6271 pF capacitor, when at 10.95 MHz. That demonstrates the effect. Thanks. I would answer the question "Can reactive components affect resistive impedance of circuit" as "yes" and now I know that. thanks!

Comment: Not quite; the operating frequency for resistive impedance matching is exactly 10.000000 MHz and, it so happens that the true resonance frequency is 10.95 MHz (an incidental value but worth reporting in the calculator to the user). On a low-pass L-pad like this, true resistive impedance matching is always at a frequency a shade below true resonance.

Comment: ok, good that you mention, i misread your website. but, the big picture, for why complex conjugate can be found by adding only reactive components even if the resistances are not matched, I think I understand now, thanks to your example. it was simple. I think it can be simplified even more, but, it was the most simple I could find so thanks for that!

Comment: @Andyaka - If you have concerns with another answer, you are allowed to politely & constructively raise those concerns *in comments on that answer*. You have done that, which is fine. It is not allowed to turn one answer into arguments against another answer. We've seen it before, it ended badly (and with suspensions for site disruption IIRC). Therefore I have rolled-back your edit. In this case, if you are unable, with polite comments (or now chat, as comments have become excessive) to reach a meeting of minds on another answer, please disengage. The OP can't be forced to change their answer.

Comment: @SamGibson is it OK if I reinstate the amendment but written in a way that doesn't explicitly call-out another answer. I would like to explain that the process I'm describing is 100% energy efficient.

Comment: @Andyaka - Re: "*is it OK if I reinstate the amendment [...]*" I can't say yes or no until you do it, to see exact wording etc. Doing that would be a risk. || *Clarification* of an answer is allowed & encouraged, but an answer must be an answer to the question, not a disagreement with another answer. The more you phrase any edit of your answer to better address the *question*, rather than responding to another *answer*, the less likely it is to appear as a disagreement with another answer or as "meta". It would be less risky to either disengage or to reply politely in the chat instead. Thanks.

Comment: OK @SamGibson I've added it and believe it to be non-contentious.

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is: yes, but, the terminology might be misleading. Andy gave a great example of a simple circuit where reactive components "change the real component of the impedance". But, what the reactive components were really doing, was act like a "voltage increaser", much like a boost converter. At the cost of drawing a lot more current (6x more in Andy's example), they could pump up the voltage ahead of the load, so that the power P = V^2/R was increased. *A new person learning about the topic might be looking more for a resistance decrease than voltage increase (even if they are the same from one point of view, it might not be the easiest point of view to take for the person asking the question) and that is why I mention that for anyone else who had the same question I had.*

The concept of "maximum power transmission" can be explained in a simple way. The source has a resistance that you cannot change (although you can remove the reactance. ) This means it will act as a voltage divider together with the load resistance. And, the power in the load happens to peak at 50% voltage divider. If more than half is lost at source, there is less voltage left at load. If less than half is lost at load, there is higher series resistance between source and load.

Since 50% voltage divider gives highest power in load, the resistance/impedance of the load should ideally be changed to the same value as the source (so, either increased, or decreased, unless it is exact same to start with. )

The reactance of the source can conveniently be removed, by the opposite phase in the load. This reduces source impedance, and increases power in load by decreasing the series resistance of source and load (but, from that increased power, we still have to divide the source voltage by half with a load resistance matched to the source, but we start off from a better position. )

And, then back to the question: *can reactive components affect resistive impedance of circuit.* They can for example, as in Andy's example, act as a "voltage increaser", to make the 300 Ohm load "behave" as if it was a 50 Ohm resistor. But, it only "behaves" that way, because the voltage was increased before it by 2.45x. I think the terminology used is a bit misleading, and that it can make it harder for beginners to learn the topic. At least I feel like if I had it explained to myself in the way I explained it here, I would have gotten it quicker.

Credit to Andy's example on his website: http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20LP.html.

Comment: There is no power loss in the circuit example I showed.

Comment: Not looking for an argument or anything like that. to quote your website: "Apart from the losses in the source's series output resistance, the power transferred is 100%." Power over source alone, is 4x power after voltage divider between source and load. I think your example was great, it was really helpful, and the best I could find.

Comment: You said *"At the cost of wasting a lot more current"* and, there is no current wasted at all; all the energy taken from the output of the 50 ohm source is transferred to the higher resistance load. Nothing is wasted. The analogy with a boost converter is not great; it's much closer to a step up transformer that is optimized at one frequency. And no, absolutely no power increase at all. I don't know how you could possibly think that power can be increased. All my comments are on your first paragraph because I gave up reading your answer after that due to the anomalies.

Comment: And, I don't know why you are making such a significantly flawed commentary of my answer in your answer. Then you criticize my answer by saying it only behaves that way because the circuit increases the output voltage; this shows a lack of comprehension of what energy efficient impedance converters do; there is NO OPTION other than to increase the voltage when stepping up a lower impedance to a higher one.

Comment: I wrote an answer to the question. It is not related to you, other than that it mentions I understood it from the example on your website. I'm not looking for an argument. I think your example was very good. And I wrote the answer I think best answers the question.

Comment: You are criticizing my answer nevertheless and therefore, I am entitled to point out that your criticism is baseless.

Comment: I’m not looking for an argument. My answer is unrelated to your answer, besides that I mention the example on your website, that you also mention in your answer. I managed to figure things out by simulating that circuit and entering the values from your calculator in your website. It was a great example and a great resource, as I said consistently.

Comment: This is the baseless criticism: *But, it only "behaves" that way, because the voltage was increased before it by 2.45x. I think the terminology used is a bit misleading*. In other words, you are saying it in a way that suggests some kind of cheap-trick way to achieve impedance matching. And also this: *But, what the reactive components were really doing, was act like a "voltage increaser", much like a boost converter.*

Comment: It is not related to your answer. I mean, in electronics in general there is a terminology. I address that. I was interested in the question and familiar with the terminology all unrelated to you. You provided the best practical example I have seen, with your website. And thanks to that I could simulate and study the effect.

Comment: Then what is your answer about? I see no merit in it.

Comment: Well, this is a Q&A platform with many users. Not everyone is in agreement all the time. The up and downvote buttons are a mechanism to reach average sentiment. I upvoted yours and thank you for the example on your website!

Comment: You said this: *At the cost of wasting a lot more current (6x more in Andy's example), they could pump up the voltage ahead of the load, so that the power P = V^2/R was increased.* <-- and that is an utter falsehood. This is the sort of thing that I strongly object to about your answer. The method I show is 100% energy efficient.

Comment: I've moved this comment section [to the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145869/discussion-between-bipedaljoe-and-andy-aka), and any continued discussion can happen there /Johan

Comment: This answer misrepresents what I'm saying in my answer. The statement in the above answer says: **At the cost of wasting a lot more current (6x more in Andy's example)**, and, that is a fallacy, misrepresentation and an untruth. The method implied by my answer is energy 100% efficient and, despite numerous attempts to explain this to the OP he refuses to budge.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. That topic is addressed in the chat. It is not about your answer. It is about how the matching network in your example (that exists outside your example too) works to increase voltage into the load. It does that in a way very similar to a boost converter. Boost converters increase voltage by drawing more current. "Using" or "drawing" may be better term than "wasting", but, it is understandable regardless. 60% of the current does not pass through the load, much like in any "voltage increaser".

Comment: Oh, so now you are saying that it isn't 6x the current but more like 2.5x the current? Don't you see that your answer misrepresents my answer and, you now appear to be admitting to that.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. This can be discussed in chat. My answer is not about your answer, besides using the example (that you also have on your website), it only addresses the circuit example (that I also simulated, and exists regardless of your example). 6x increase in current through circuit with 300 Ohm load vs a 300 Ohm load without matching network. 40% passes through load, 60% outside. There is a chat where you can discuss.

Comment: And, where does that extra current go I might ask. Your comment appears to imply that a "voltage" increaser" has the same current at the output as the input. Well, you need to study boost converters more carefully because, an ideal boost converter must have a bigger current at the input if the output voltage is higher than the input voltage. It's a fundamental law of physics; power out equals power in for a 100% efficient process.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussions in comments. The discussion will be addressed in chat. It is welcome, but, [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145869/discussion-between-bipedaljoe-and-andy-aka).